# Performance with Yeppp! is slower than native implementation

Tags: c++, performance, math, vector, yeppp

Hi I am trying to improve the performance of vector algebra in my code using Yeppp! library however the performance is actually getting worse... 
Here is a piece of the Vector class code:

```
#include "Vector3.h"
#include <cmath>
#include "yepCore.h"

Vector3::Vector3()
{
    //ctor
}

Vector3::~Vector3()
{
    //dtor
}

Vector3::Vector3(float X, float Y, float Z)
{
    x = X;
    y = Y;
    z = Z;
}


float& Vector3::operator[](int idx)
{
    return (&x)[idx];
}

Vector3& Vector3::normalize()
{
#if USE_YEPPP
    float inf;
    yepCore_SumSquares_V32f_S32f(&x, &inf, 3);
    yepCore_Multiply_IV32fS32f_IV32f(&x, 1.0f / sqrt(inf), 3);
#else
    float inf = 1.0f / sqrt((x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z));
    x *= inf;
    y *= inf;
    z *= inf;
#endif
    return *this;

}

Vector3 Vector3::cross(Vector3& rh)
{
    return Vector3 (
                (y * rh.z) - (z * rh.y),
                (z * rh.x) - (x * rh.z),
                (x * rh.y) - (y * rh.x)
    );
}

float Vector3::dot(Vector3& rh)
{
#if USE_YEPPP
    float ret = 0;
    yepCore_DotProduct_V32fV32f_S32f(&x, &rh.x, &ret, 3);
    return ret;
#else
    return x*rh.x+y*rh.y+z*rh.z;
#endif
}

Vector3 Vector3::operator*(float scalar)
{
#if USE_YEPPP
    Vector3 ret;
    yepCore_Multiply_V32fS32f_V32f(&x, scalar, &ret.x , 3);
    return ret;
#else
    return Vector3(x*scalar, y*scalar,z*scalar);
#endif
}

Vector3 Vector3::operator+(Vector3 rh)
{
#if USE_YEPPP
    Vector3 ret;
    yepCore_Add_V32fV32f_V32f(&x, &rh.x, &ret.x, 3);
    return ret;
#else
    return Vector3(x+rh.x, y+rh.y, z+rh.z);
#endif
}

Vector3 Vector3::operator-(Vector3 rh)
{
#if USE_YEPPP
    Vector3 ret;
    yepCore_Subtract_V32fV32f_V32f(&x, &rh.x, &ret.x, 3);
    return ret;
#else
    return Vector3(x-rh.x, y-rh.y, z-rh.z);
#endif
}

Vector3 operator*(float s, const Vector3& v)
{
#if USE_YEPPP
    Vector3 ret;
    yepCore_Multiply_V32fS32f_V32f(&v.x, s, &ret.x , 3);
    return ret;
#else
    return Vector3(s*v.x,s*v.y,s*v.z);
#endif
}
```

I am using g++ compiler.
Compiler options: g++ -Wall -fexceptions  -fPIC -Wl,--no-as-needed -std=c++11 -pthread  -ggdb
Linker options: g++ -shared -lpthread -lyeppp -ldl

So any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think YEPPP uses the same formulas to calculate things you do, plus the overhead of checking if the arguments make sense. Usually libraries only improve performance if their algorithms are better than yours, which in this case is difficult to do because... it's only maths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeppp! is optimized for processing arrays of 100+ elements.

It is not efficient on small arrays (like length-3 array in your example) due to limited ability to use SIMD and overheads of function call, dynamic dispatching, and parameter checks.

Comment: Thanks Marat. That was my suspicion as well. So I guess there is no way to optimize it farther for single object operations...